# A Local Server Configuration for Single Page Applications

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, localhost, single-page-application

I am looking for a local server configuration that will correctly serve single page applications that utilize push state.  This server configuration needs to serve the single page(index.html) for all configured routes but serve assets based on url requested.  The Backbone router in the single page will handle customization based on the url.

url:       /
serves: /index.html

url:       /any/configured/path
serves: /index.html

You can use any server but I prefer one for development work that has a simple setup/install such as:

- [Python's SimpleHttpServer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html)
- [connect (npm package)](https://npmjs.org/package/connect)

Comment: Have you already tried SimpleHttpServer & Connect?

Comment: I'm currently using SimpleHttpServer but don't have it configured.  I also have some Ruby servers installed like Thin and WEBrick.